# Javascript reportvalidity() only working every other time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some form validation and I'm having an issue with `reportvalidity()` function.

Basically what I'm trying to do is that when the user is done filling an input and the input is incorrectly filled, the user will get an error message with what's wrong with what he filled.

So for the email field I'm using a eventlistener on input which checks for a pattern mismatch and set a custom validity depending on the result, and an eventlistener on blur which `reportvalidity` on the input field. My issue is that while it works fine the first time he leaves the input field, when I go back to it to make some correction, if the input is still wrongs it won't display the error message then. I have to go back to the input, then leaves it again for the message to show again.

I tried wraping the `reportvalidity` into a `setTimeout`, which fixed this issue but then the user is not able to leave the input while it's incorrectly filled, which is another issue. I'm kind of lost as to why the first try is not working.

Here's a codepen with the code :
https://codepen.io/chibbi/pen/ZEEXZeR

Thanks a lot for your help.

Here's the JS :

```
const email = document.querySelector('#email');


function customMessage(event) {
  const { target } = event;
  if (target.validity.patternMismatch) {
    target.setCustomValidity('Enter a valid email adress');
  } else {
    target.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
email.addEventListener('input', customMessage);

email.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
  customMessage(event);
  if (email.value !== '') {
    email.reportValidity();
  }
});
```

Comment: Please update the question with your code.

Comment: what do you mean ? Should I post the whole JS code here ? I thought it'd be easier in a codepen

Answer (score 0):

I have spent quite some time with this very same bug, and I thought I should write my findings here, just in case someone else has the same issue.

Apparently, the "validating every second time" is a default Firefox behavior when the reportValidity() is set on the "blur" event. Chrome and Safari have no issues with this.

Example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input step attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="points">Points:</label>
  <input onblur="this.reportValidity()" type="number" id="points" name="points" step="3">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I solved this by adding the reportValidity() function to "focusout" event. This, however, caused Safari to not show validation anymore.

So my final solution was to check if the browser is Firefox and then add validation to focusOut, otherwise leave the validation to blur.

Don't know if that's the best solution but maybe it helps (also added my code below as an example).

```js
let browserFirefox = !(window.mozInnerScreenX == null);

if (browserFirefox) {
    me._on(me._$input, 'focusout', $.proxy(me.validateInputValue, me));
    me._on(me._$input, 'focusout', $.proxy(me._$input.attr('onfocusout', 'this.reportValidity()'), me));
} else {
    me._on(me._$input, 'blur', $.proxy(me.validateInputValue, me));
}
```